# Content assist issue involving template parameters

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-cdt, content-assist

I'm using Eclipse Luna (4.4.0) CDT, and I'm coding in C++11.

Sometimes, content assist doesn't work when template classes are involved. Here is an example:

```
template<class T>
class Test {
    vector<T> test1;

    void blah() {
        vector<T> test2 = test1;
        test2. //content assist finds the members of vector<T>
        test1. //content assist finds nothing
    }
};
```

The code still compiles if I call e.g. `test1.size()`. Variations such as `this->test1.` also don't work.

How do I get content assist to work?